# How to have the list of links from PowerPoint in a dropdown list

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I need to have a list of all links in PowerPoint in a dropdown list in a form.

To find the links I have already the following code:

```
Sub listing()
    Dim oSld As Slide
    Dim oSh As Shape
        For Each oSld In ActivePresentation.Slides
        For Each oSh In oSld.Shapes
    
       If oSh.Type = msoLinkedPicture Or oSh.Type = msoLinkedOLEObject Then
           Path = oSh.LinkFormat.SourceFullName
           Position = InStr(1, Path, "!", vbTextCompare)
           FileName = Left(Path, Position - 1)
           
           MsgBox FileName ' This will lists each link one by one
       End If
   Next oSh
Next oSld
End Sub
```

The code above will also produce duplicates as multiple objects have the same link but different ranges in Excel. For example, to the list I need should contain only unique values

To fill in the dropdown in the form I have this code:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

    If ComboBox2.ListCount = 0 Then
        AddDropDownItems
    End If
End Sub

Sub AddDropDownItems()
    ComboBox2.AddItem "1"
    ComboBox2.AddItem "2"
    ComboBox2.AddItem "3"
End Sub
```

What I can not figure out is how to merge both codes so that it lists the links in the dropdown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

In the **UserForm1 module**

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Dim oSld As Slide, oSh As Shape
    
    Dim list As New Collection  'declare and make new Collection
    
    For Each oSld In ActivePresentation.Slides
        For Each oSh In oSld.Shapes
            If oSh.Type = msoLinkedPicture Or oSh.Type = msoLinkedOLEObject Then
                Path = oSh.LinkFormat.SourceFullName
                Position = InStr(1, Path, "!", vbTextCompare)
                If Position > 0 Then Path = Left(Path, Position - 1)
                
                ' adding paths to the collection to avoid
                ' duplication (duplicate keys are not allowed)
                ' also you can use Dictionary object with .Exist() method
                On Error Resume Next
                list.Add Path, Path ' add Path as an item and as a key
                On Error GoTo 0
            End If
        Next oSh
    Next oSld
    
    With Me.ComboBox2
        .Clear
        For Each el In list
            .AddItem el 'add Paths from Collection
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

In the **standard module**

```
Sub test()
    UserForm1.Show
End Sub
```

Comment: Exactly what I wanted. Thanks!!